# How to calculate values from previous month to current month

Tags: postgresql

> I want to calculate this table. Everytime that there is a new participant per month it will add the previous value to current value.

| month | no_participant |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-01 | 10 |
| 2021-02 | 20 |
| 2021-03 | 5 |
| 2021-04 | 17 |

> Something like this, output

| month | no_participant | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01 | 10 | 10 |
| 2021-02 | 20 | 30 |
| 2021-03 | 5 | 35 |
| 2021-04 | 17 | 52 |

> Here's my query: I am using Postgres. Thanks to your help

```
SELECT (TO_CHAR(CSD.SCHEDULED_START_DATETIME, 'YYYY-MM'))AS MONTH,
COUNT(DISTINCT PARTICIPANT_ID) AS PARTICIPANT

FROM TSUP.COURSE_SCHEDULE_DETAIL AS CSD

INNER JOIN TSUP.COURSE_PARTICIPANT AS CP
ON CSD.COURSE_SCHEDULE_ID = CP.COURSE_SCHEDULE_ID

INNER JOIN(

SELECT
MIN(COALESCE(CSD.RESCHEDULED_START_DATETIME, CSD.SCHEDULED_START_DATETIME)) AS SCHEDULED_START_DATETIME,
MAX(COALESCE(CSD.RESCHEDULED_END_DATETIME, CSD.SCHEDULED_END_DATETIME)) AS SCHEDULED_END_DATETIME,
COUNT(CSD.SCHEDULED_START_DATETIME) AS "COUNT"
    
FROM TSUP.COURSE_SCHEDULE_DETAIL AS CSD

INNER JOIN (
SELECT CP.PARTICIPANT_ID AS "PARTICIPANT", 
MIN(COALESCE(CSD.RESCHEDULED_START_DATETIME, CSD.SCHEDULED_START_DATETIME)) AS SCHEDULED_START_DATETIME, 
MAX(COALESCE(CSD.RESCHEDULED_END_DATETIME, CSD.SCHEDULED_END_DATETIME)) AS SCHEDULED_END_DATETIME

FROM TSUP.COURSE_PARTICIPANT AS CP

INNER JOIN TSUP.COURSE_SCHEDULE_DETAIL AS CSD
ON CP.COURSE_SCHEDULE_ID = CSD.COURSE_SCHEDULE_ID
INNER JOIN TSUP.COURSE_SCHEDULE AS CS
ON CSD.ID = CS.ID
INNER JOIN TSUP.COURSE AS C
ON CS.COURSE_ID = C.ID
INNER JOIN TSUP.COURSE_CATEGORY AS CC
ON C.COURSE_CATEGORY_ID = CC.ID
INNER JOIN TSUP.EMPLOYEE AS E
ON CP.PARTICIPANT_ID = E.ID
INNER JOIN TSUP.MEMBER_ROLE AS MR
ON E.MEMBER_ROLE_ID = MR.ID

WHERE C.MANDATORY = 'Yes'
AND MR.ROLE_TYPE = 'Dev'
AND CC.CATEGORY = 'JJ'

GROUP BY CP.PARTICIPANT_ID) 
TEMP ON CSD.SCHEDULED_START_DATETIME = TEMP.SCHEDULED_START_DATETIME
GROUP BY CSD.RESCHEDULED_START_DATETIME, CSD.SCHEDULED_START_DATETIME,
CSD.RESCHEDULED_END_DATETIME, CSD.SCHEDULED_END_DATETIME
)
TEMP ON CSD.SCHEDULED_START_DATETIME = TEMP.SCHEDULED_START_DATETIME

GROUP BY MONTH
```

Answer (score 1):

The query you provided is verbose, and also does not seem to exactly line up with the sample data.  I will give the following query based on the sample data shown:

```sql
SELECT month, no_participant, SUM(no_participant) OVER (ORDER BY month) AS count
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY month;
```

The above logic uses `SUM()` as an analytic function.